# How to execute multiple operations while updating an item in Amazon DynamoDB?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to update an item in Amazon DynamoDB. I want to execute an operation that consists of one sum and one subtraction, but I'm not able to accomplish my goal.

Here is the function, `ddb` is an instance of the class `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient`:

```
function updateLecture(event){
    const params = {
        TableName: 'lecture',
        Key: {
            'lecture_id': Number.parseInt(event.lecture_id)
        },
        UpdateExpression: 'SET #free = :total - (#total + #free)',
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':total': event.total
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames: {
            "#total" : "total",
            "#free" : "free"
        },
        ReturnValues : 'UPDATED_NEW'
    }
    
    return ddb.update(params).promise();
}
```

When I try to run the function, I get the following error:

```
"errorType": "ValidationException",
"errorMessage": "Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: \"+\", near: \"#total + #free\""
```

I've tried to work with parenthesis, but I always receive the same error.

I'm afraid I can't use more than one operation, but I couldn't find any trace of that in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html#Expressions.UpdateExpressions.SET.IncrementAndDecrement). Anyway, is there a way to use multiple operations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tried the following PartiQL statement in the DynamoDB console, and it worked fine:

```
// Works just fine
UPDATE "ddb-playground" 
SET myNumA = 10 - (myNumB + myNumA)
WHERE PK = 'foo' AND SK = 'bar'
```

It runs just fine, so at least there's no fundamental limitation here.

However, just like you, I'm not able to get the JS SDK to do this with an UpdateExpression, I get syntax error no matter what I try. So it seems like the JS SDK is limited to a single arithmetic expression on numeric values.

```
// Fails with:
//
// ValidationException: Invalid UpdateExpression: Syntax error; token: "+", near: "myNumB + myNumA"
import AWS from "aws-sdk"
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB()

await ddb.putItem({
    TableName: "ddb-playground",
    Item: {
        PK: {S: "foo"},
        SK: {S: "bar"},
        myNumA: {N: "10"},
        myNumB: {N: "20"}
    }
}).promise()


await ddb.updateItem({
    TableName: "ddb-playground",
    Key: {
        PK: {S: "foo"},
        SK: {S: "bar"}
    },
    UpdateExpression: "SET myNumA = :newVal - (myNumB + myNumA)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
        ":newVal": {N: "30"}
    }
}).promise()
```

So perhaps your only option here is to actually use PariQL for this one?

```
await ddb.executeStatement({
  Statement: 'UPDATE "ddb-playground" SET myNumA = ? - (myNumB + myNumA) WHERE PK = ? AND SK = ?',
  Parameters: [{N: "30"}, {S: "foo"}, {S: "bar"}]
}).promise()
```

Comment: Hi , thank you for your answer. When you execute `ddb.executeStatement`, what type of object is `ddb`? Cause the class `AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient` has not such method. Sure enough, when I try to execute that statement I get the error `ddb.executeStatement is not a function`

Comment: Okay I think `ddb` is an instance of `AWS.DynamoDB`. If you update the answer, I'll accept it

Comment: Good point, important context, I've added an example of how I create `ddb` in the code :)